# Как вывести цену товара в woocomerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Всем доброго времени суток.
Нужно сделать калькулятор для товаров,на каждой странице,для этого нужно в инпут вставить цену товара,на странице которого мы находимся.
Написал такой инпут

```
<input type="text" id="price" value="" disabled>
```

А вот,что в value вставлять - без понятия.
Гугл выдал такое:

```
$product->get_price_html() ;
```

НО,когда я вставляю,ломается страница.
Так же,решил вывести $product

```
var_dump($product);
```

Вывелось

> string(7) "classic"

то есть у товара есть только название,хотя в админке указал и цену,и изображение..
Так же нужно уточнить,что убрал вывод цены на странице товара.
Заранее благодарю за ответы и простите за такое кривое объяснение)

Comment: В какой файл вы это вставляете? Явно не туда. $product - это глобальная переменная, объект, содержащий все характеристики товара. У вас же эта переменная перебита какой-то строкой. Потому и попытка вставить правильный код из Google рушит страницу - у строки нет и не может быть метода get_price_html(). Покажите ваш файл, в общем.

Comment: @KAGGDesign Благодарю за ответ.Я уже разобрался,я просто не объявил переменную в этом файле.вставляю в файл themes/betheme(название темы)/woocommerce/content-product.php
Вот ссылка на код (https://pastebin.com/7Eu6dZeM 163 строка)
НО тут он не вставляет в инпут значение,а вставляет "₽2,150.00" disabled>" буду благодарен,если поможете с моей проблемой.

Comment: @KAGGDesign мне нужно сделать простой калькулятор.который высчитывал бы ЦЕНА_ТОВАРА*КОЛ-ВО,поэтому я создал 2 импута и хотелось бы,чтобы в первом всегда отображалась цена,товара на странице которого мы находимся,и уже работать с ней

Comment: ну у вас цена и есть - 2150 рублей.

Comment: @KAGGDesign не,я имею в виду,то,что он html тэг вставляет,а не в инпут значение,вот скрин http://imgur.com/a/EAQiM

Comment: @KAGGDesign все понял,спасибо,просто прочитал внимательнее документацию)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я использовал `<?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?>` для вывода цены товара. `get_` лишь получает значение, нужно просто вывести на экран.

Answer (score 0):

`get_price_html()` - это ваш метод,который применяется для сущности `$product`. Вместе оно возвращает `value` для вашего `input`. Я не вижу саму форму но `input` будет лежать в каком то div. Вот пример того что должно получится:
В самом view(html)-

`<div id='my_input'></div>`

В php:

```
woocommerce_form_field( 'my_input', array(
'type' => 'text',
'class' => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
'label' => __('My input')  . '</br>',
'placeholder' => __('0.00'), 
'value' => $product->get_price_html()
) );
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ,как я понимаю,можно просто в value="<?= $product->get_price_html();?>" вставить,но загвоздка в том,что в $product ничего нет,кроме названия,то есть цену неоткуда брать.

Comment: Воспользовался вашим методом  - тоже не работает,причину написал в прошлом комменте.

Comment: извините, мою глупость, я не знаю почему я так подумал,переменная то в php, я сейчас поправлю ответ

Comment: формы никакой нет есть просто импут и лейбл.Почему нельзя просто в value="<?= $product->get_price_html();?>"  подставить?

Comment: Так же не совсем понятно куда вставать php код,я думал сделать все папке темы/woocomerce-content-single-product.php.Надеюсь на ваш ответ.

Comment: зачем вы пишете теги php в таком виде `<?= ?>`? Попробуйте написать `<?php ?>`. Проблема может скрываться в этом

Comment: Написал так <?php echo $product->get_price_html();?>,все равно не пашет :С

Comment: прилинкуйте файл с используемым методом к вашему файлу, а потом можно будет использовать его методы
<?php require('woocomerce-content-single-product.php'); ?>

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59813/discussion-between-tweeker-and--).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php woocommerce_template_loop_price(); ?>
```

попробуй так эту стандартный хук вукомера